# Re.findall() can't take a variable as an argument

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am attempting [Problem 20](http://projecteuler.net/problem=20) on Project Euler and this is the solution that I have so far:

```
import re
mylist = []
var1 = 100
def exclamation(n, L):
    for n in xrange(1, (n)):
        L.append(n)
        n -= 1
    print L
def multiply(L, V):
    while len(L) > 0:
        V = L.pop(-1) * V
    print V
exclamation(100, mylist)
multiply(mylist, var1)
print mylist
list1 = re.findall('.', var1)
print list1
```

However, re.findall only takes strings, and I was wondering if there was something else that did the same job or an escape character to tell it that it is a variable.

I have tried putting a "/" in front of it as well as "/escape" which I think I found on the python documentation, however it didn't work.

Comment: Can you explain why you're trying to use regex?  If you're trying to get each number, you're probably better off using [slice notation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Comment: I don't know much python, I'm a bit of a noob :/ Thanks for the hint though :)

Comment: @ernie how do you get all of the characters into a list if you can't run a for loop on it?

Comment: Why can't you run a loop?  If I were you, I'd save the output of multiply into a string, and then take slices of it (e.g. V[0], V[1], V[2], etc)

Comment: @ernie Is it possible to run a for loop on something that isn't iterable? # fixed the not defined bit

Comment: I would get the factorial output into a string, and then loop over it in slices, e.g.:

a = '1234567890'
for in in range( 0, len(a) ):
  print a[i]

Comment: I understand the rest, but what does "for in in" do, did you mean "for a in"?

Comment: nope, that line could be simplied to something like "for i in range(0,10)";  range returns a list, so it's iterable, so it could be re-written as "for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about whether it's a *variable* or not. It's about whether or not it's a *string*. Just make the argument a string. If `var1` is an int, this is very easy:

```
re.findall('.', str(var1))
```

Comment: Thanks, it's recognised var1 :)